When an electric oven junction box needs to be relocated can a whip be run from the old box under US NEC 2014?
Our double wall oven went kaput and had to be replaced. Discovered today that the new oven  and the old oven (same manufacturer) want the junction box in different locations.
Is it code-compliant (NEC 2014) to run a 4' whip from the old junction box? The wires are 3-conductor stranded aluminum 4AWG for 50A oven. Does a 4AWG whip exist?

Better make sure the oven can actually connect to aluminum wires - often they are copper only.

Especially considering that 4AWG is large enough that it won't fit in a MAC-Block (you'll need a much chunkier Polaris instead)

3 conductor as in Hot-Hot-Neutral (because oven light) not Hot-Hot-Neutral-Ground or Hot-Hot-Ground? Extending it might incur an obligation to retrofit a grounding conductor.

Thanks.  Followup question.  The Electrical specs say the oven is 7.2Kw at 240V and that a dedicated 30A circuit is recommended. Do I need to make any adjustments to that 30A recommendation seeing as it is a double-oven? Could I have the electrician remove the 50A breaker, put in a 40A, and run 4-conductor copper 8AWG wire?

The specs for your double oven call for 30A@240V. Being it's a double oven they have already made any "adjustment" needed. If it were a pair of single ovens, that would be different. So give it exactly what the instructions say.
